# Libspellchecker plugin not loading in codeblocks that is installed in ubuntu 19.10

Tags: software-installation

When i start codeblocks, in ubuntu 19.10, a warning pops up on codeblocks "libspellchecker.so did not install. I checked settings-editor and spellchecker was not there. Being new to linux, my google search turned up nothing. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

A only temporary way to resolve this warning issue is to go to `usr/lib/codeblocks/plugins` and remove (as root) the`libSpellChecker.so` file

With that the warning will disappear

I haven't figured out a better way to fix the problem, which in my case is happening in Debian